# Cannot show notification using FCM to standalone Apple tvOS

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging, tvos, apple-tv

#### Description

I am developing a standalone app for Apple tvOS. I am running the following code

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    @AppStorage("fcmToken") var fToken = ""
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // Register for remote notifications
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Push Notifications

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("APNS device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] != nil {
            print("Received data message: \(userInfo)")
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Messaging

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
        fToken = fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    
}

@main
struct SomeExampleApp_TVApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I am also getting this from console

```
2023-04-24 20:04:46.212321+0530 SomeExampleApp[1262:39696] void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void * _Nullable): map table argument is NULL
2023-04-24 20:04:46.221547+0530 SomeExampleApp[1262:39865] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '012849237482'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
FCM token: someFcmToken
2023-04-24 20:04:48.650580+0530 SomeExampleApp[1262:39858] [] nw_path_necp_check_for_updates Failed to copy updated result (22)
FCM token: someFcmToken
APNS device token: someApnToken
Received data message: [AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Entry Lights turned on as you entered Office";
        title = "Location Automation";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 984386421852, AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): citAzVs8zUeFtNaj_EZJmN, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1682346907169586]
Received data message: [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1682347026515009, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Entry Lights turned on as you entered Office";
        title = "Location Automation";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): citAzVs8zUeFtNaj_EZJmN, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 012849237482]
Received data message: [AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Entry Lights turned on as you entered Office";
        title = "Location Automation";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 984386421852, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1682347042989389, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): citAzVs8zUeFtNaj_EZJmN]
```

#### Firebase SDK Version

9.6.0

#### Xcode Version

Version 14.2 (14C18)

#### Installation Method

Swift Package Manager

#### Firebase Product(s)

Messaging

#### Targeted Platforms

tvOS

Run above code as tvos with firebase cloud messaging and apn setup.